# how could I solve "a result has failed to un-serialize. please ensure that the objects returned by the function are always picklable." when I run LDA？

Tags: python, lda, pyldavis

When I use the `pyLDAvis.gensim` functoion to construct visualization at google colab, it shows this error:

> a result has failed to un-serialize. please ensure that the objects
> returned by the function are always picklable.

My codes are:

```
!pip install pyldavis
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.gensim_models as pg
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()

vis = pg.prepare(lda, corpus, dictionary, sort_topics=False) # construct visualization
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading pandas to '1.2.0' version worked for me.